# foreach loop keeps adding previouse result to the next in each table row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to create a table that shows the date of a training plan, the plan its self and the members of the group that can attend.
The first two are no problem but its who can attend that is the issue.
The attendees is stored as a string in the database and explode it to an array but when i use a foreach loop to display the arrays it adds the previous row to the next.

The code I have is:

```
    $sql_group_name = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT groupName,accepted FROM maingroup");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_group_name)){
$accepted= $row["accepted"];
$groupName = $row["groupName"];
$accept_array = explode(",", $accepted);
if (in_array($u,$accept_array)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM training WHERE groupName='$groupName' ORDER BY sessDate ASC";
    $training_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($training_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $date = $row["sessDate"];
        $session = htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['plan']), ENT_QUOTES);
        $groupName = $row["groupName"];
        $attending = $row["attending"];
        $attend_array = explode(",",$attending);
        foreach($attend_array as $value){
            $attendList .=  "" .$value. "<br/>";
        } 

        if (in_array($u,$attend_array)){
            $attendBtn = '<form name="sessUnAttend" id="sessUnAttend" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" value="Unattend">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="' .$id. '">
                                <input type="hidden" name="unattend" id="unattend">
                                </form>';

        } else { $attendBtn = '<form name="sessAttend" id="sessAttend" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" value="Attend">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="' .$id. '">
                                <input type="hidden" name="attend" id="attend">
                                </form>';

    }

        $sessTable .= '<tr>
                        <td>' .$date. '</td>
                        <td>' .$session. '</td>     
                        <td>' .$groupName. '</td>
                        <td>' .$attendList. '</td>
                        <td>' .$attendBtn. '</td>
                        </tr>';
    }
}
    }
```

the result I get is:

Date |      Plan   |    Attending

4.4.16  |   some plan | me

5.4.16   |  some plan | me, me

6.4.16  |   some plan | me, me

Obviuosly "me" can only attend once. It would keep repeating me,me until some one else said they could attend and then add their name and repeat that until some one else said the could attend and so on.

I have read that the while loop should be `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array` but that seems to mess every thing else up.

Comment: Reset `$attendList` to `''` when you get a change of date/plan

Comment: your code is so messy. first of all where the `$u` comes from? let's assume, outside of this code. But the very problem is, that you looping on `$row` in first query, and the inside loop your overwrite that `$row`. Please fix it first.

Comment: @lolka_bolka - yes the $u variable is established eslwhere in the page, sorry should of said that but didn't want to post the whole page of code that mostly had nothing to do with the issue. I have tried changing the inner while loop to $row1 but it seems to do nothing to the result. is this what you meant?

Comment: @MarkBaker how would you go about setting `$attendList` to `''`. If i put it in the foreach loop or out side the foreach loop it would send everything to `''` as that is the last call of the variable. or have i miss understood?

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you for your comment, i showed it to a friend who clarified what you meant and it works perfect now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @MarkBaker did the trick with some more help from a friend.

All i had to do was reset the `$attendList` variable.

```
     $sessTable .= '<tr>
                    <td>' .$date. '</td>
                    <td>' .$session. '</td>     
                    <td>' .$groupName. '</td>
                    <td>' .$attendList. '</td>
                    <td>' .$attendBtn. '</td>
                    </tr>';
                    $attendList = '';
```

What was happening was the variable was being set from the previous loop and then it just stayed as that until more got added to it.

What happens now is each time the loop finishes it resets the variable so the new id starts from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to unset the id:

```
unset($accepted);
```

Comment: I tried putting your suggestion in the foreach loop under the `$attendList .=  "" .$value. "<br/>";` but it didn't change anything. is this where you meant or should i put it somewhere else?